# how to store & retrive a link in database in rails?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have question and answer functionality in rails, with the answer field as a text area. When the user enters a link in the answer field, how do I display it as a link when displaying results?

Answer (score 2):

Before or after you save the answer text, you can add the html for a link to any text recognized as a link, using an add-on gem. One option is [rails_autolink](https://github.com/tenderlove/rails_autolink), another is [rinku](https://github.com/bquorning/rinku).